# Can't find the semantic link between parts of the sentence

Tags: meaning

I can't find the semantic link between parts of the sentence. It just doesn't seem right to me.

> But if data is any indication, even as the beverage chain tries to tackle racial and income disparity, it remains a symbol of it.
>
> [Eater.com](http://www.eater.com/a/starbucks-income-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the introductory clause at the end:

> Even as Starbucks tries to deal with its image as the server to the
>   white upperclass, it remains a symbol of that status, if data is any
>   indication.

The data in question is the map you link to, which shows Starbuck's locations superimposed on a map of Chicago, with areas shaded by income.  Guess where the Starbuck's are.

Comment: +1. A piece of data missing from that article—the *price* of a cup of coffee at Starbucks.